# Remove ALL css for a specific plugin page

Tags: plugins, css

I'm now writing a plugin that hook with a [TAG] on a page. From now every thing work well except for the custom css. I've writing my plugin on a developement station with basic theme (20-14 I think). When I've put my plugin in the real site, that was very ugly because site theme css where not handle. There is a way to reset or remove all css in a plugin. I ask this because if one day I want to change my theme, I will have to rewrite my plugin to handle more theme css. 
From now i've tries the hard way with wp_deregister_style('slug').

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');


 function my_scripts_method() {    
//    wp_deregister_style('open-sans-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('rs-settings-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('rs-captions-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('rs-plugin-static-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('wp125style-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('u-design-reset-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('u-design-text-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('u-design-grid-960-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('u-design-superfish_menu-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('u-design-pretty_photo-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('u-design-style-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('u-design-custom-style-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('u-design-responsive-css');
//    wp_deregister_style('u-design-style-orig-css');
//and continue....
```

But it's doesn't work. Even if this work, I will have to completly re-begin if I change my theme. There is a way to put a reset css like or put everything to 0?

Sorry for my bad english, i'm french.

Francois

Comment: I assume you are trying that code _without_ the line comments?

Comment: yes, I use without the line comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this function.

```
function remove_all_theme_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    $wp_styles->queue = array();
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'remove_all_theme_styles', 100);
```

This should work on any theme, but its not really a good approach to disable theme css just to make your plugin look good.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. What other solution the plugin writer use to make their plugin to look good? I've tried the css way, but I found this hard to think all options I should put just in case of...

Comment: If you are creating a public plugin that other users will use, consider these notes.

1) Try to use unique classes and IDs for the HTML output of your plugin on the frontend.

2) Add a plugin specific CSS & js files, that will take care of design of the plugin output. 

3) Users would like to have a nice looking plugin, but not with a compromise to damage the whole theme output, so disabling the theme CSS is really a bad solution.

Comment: 4) "I've tried the css way, but I found this hard to think all options I should put just in case of... " - thats a typical problem for perfectionists usually, they want to make it perfect and include all possible features : ))

Instead, create plugin with the features you think are vital, you will develop and improve it further, also you can listen to the feedback of the users, they will give you bunch of great (and a bunch of silly as well) ideas for plugin improvement.

Comment: Thank Archie. You make one point when you said that I'm perfectionists! In fact, my plugin is in version 2. The first one was to test user reaction. The reaction was they love it, but some feature was missing. For the design output I will remember what you said! Thank again :)

Answer (score 0):

You should probaby use

```
wp_dequeue_style();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in more detail.

Comment: Sormano, thank but even if this work, it will not work anymore if I change my theme. I search for something that's definitive, something that I will not need to check anymore in case of theme changing.

Comment: Best you can do is create a css file for your plugin and set your style in there. It's not recommended to unload someones style to make your plugin work/pretty.

Comment: Sormano: I've done this so far... But it's not the best thing. If I change my theme, I will need to redo this.. :/